# Snowflake date Dynamic variable

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

My S3 path is

s3://datahub-processed-zone/pit/2022-03-25/Investor/

and Snowflake-S3 Integration is s3://datahub-processed-zone which is called com_stage. I am generating a dynamic stage and I have set variable for date.
The dyamnic stage should read all files in the Investor folder

```
set investor_pattern2 = '/'||current_date()||'\/Investor/'

ls @com_stage/pit pattern=investor_pattern2
```

but it is don't giving me any files. Can some take a look into why is it not returning me any data ?

Thanks,
Xi

Answer (score 2):

The variable needs to be prefixed with $ when you use it e.g.

```
ls @com_stage/pit pattern=$investor_pattern2
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can access string variables using [`identifier()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifier-literal.html):

```sql
ls @com_stage/pit pattern=identifier('investor_pattern2')
```